# Font-size and Font-family not changing through jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, saas

hello so this is my code : -
code
html-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="iconFavicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   
</head>
<body>
<p>My Text Has To Be Changed </>
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
<button>4</button>
<button>5</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

css-

```
.text-change{ 
    font-size:2rem;
    font-family:cursive;
    color:black;
}
```

javascript-

> $("p").addClass(".text-change")

Even after writing this statement in javascript i cannot change the font size or the font family of my text . Any kind of help would be appreciated .

Comment: Remove the dot in the jQuery code. The class itself does not have dot in its name.
$("p").addClass("text-change")

Comment: thank you @ marks .. its working now

Answer (score 2):

There is a little error in your code.

This code: `$("p").addClass(".text-change")`

Can you change it: `$("p").addClass("text-change")`

Example here: https://codepen.io/yasgo/pen/MWjWyMp